# ABS fragment crashes on onCreate

Tags: android, fragment, actionbarsherlock

i'm in need of some help regarding ActionBar Sherlock fragments.

I'm quite new to android programming but i've basically followed http://goo.gl/Nikyg (stackoverflow post) to create my fragments but the app crashes everytime i try to run on android 2.2 or 4.0

Can anyone help me? Code is as follows:

Mainactivity.java

```
package br.com.example.fragmented;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Layout file activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment class="br.com.example.fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.85" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.java

```
package br.com.example.fragmented;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("First Fragment", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("First Fragment", "onCreateView()");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment1layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#000000">

    <Button android:text="Landscape" 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone point where i am missing the error here? OH and i have set Theme to Sherlock.Light on Manifest by the way.

Added Log:

```
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.example.fragmented/br.com.example.fragmented.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:857)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at br.com.example.fragmented.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 11 more
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment br.com.example.fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 20 more
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.example.fragment1 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/br.com.example.fragmented-1.apk]
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
07-26 20:22:14.297: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 23 more
```

Comment: Crashes how?  What is the error? Did you run it in the debugger? Can you add the logcat output to give some idea of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the class attribute in your xml and use YOUR fragment's name for the name attribute, not ABS.

Comment: Ok, just added the log file. Before running i removed the class atribute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Herrera so the error is telling you to make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Comment: how do i insert the empty constructor? isn't the class being called by the layout at `android:name="br.com.example.fragment1"`?

Comment: Yes, it's being called like that, but in order to do the properly invoke the constructor of that class, the android system requires you to have a default empty constructor. Just place public Fragment1(){} in your class

Comment: Thanks for tip, but after placing constructor i still get the same error as above. Tried some changes on layout file but nothing too. Seems weird but when i replace the fragment for a ListFragment it shows a circular Progress Bar the never stops.